# Using Stormcrawler for crawling specific subdirectories

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I would like to be able crawl very specific sub-directories for a given website.

For example:
On the website `www.world.com` there maybe multiple sub-directories `/world` or `/bye`. These in-turn may contain multiple pages `/world/new` etc. Lets assume that these pages themselves contain links to other pages which may not be in the same sub-directory. ( `/world/new` has a link to `/bye/new`).

What I would like to accomplish is to crawl the contents of every page under `/world/` and only those pages.

Would it be a good idea to ignore any outgoing link unless it also belongs to the same sub-directory? I feel like a lot of the pages would not be reached because it would not be linked directly. For example `/world/new/` has a link `/bye/new` which in turn has a link to `/world/next`. This would cause the crawler to not reach the `/next` page. (If I am understanding it correctly).

The alternative would be to crawl the entire website and then filter out the content based on URL post crawl, which would make the job itself significantly larger than it needs to be.

Does Storm crawler have any configuration which could be used to make this simpler? Or maybe there is a better approach to this solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've described the two possible approaches in your question. The easiest would be to use the URL Filters and restrict to the area of the site that you are interested in but as you pointed out, you might miss some content. The alternative is indeed more expensive as you'd have to crawl the whole site and you could then filter as part of the indexing step; for this, you could add a simple parse filter to create a key /value in the metadata for URLs which **are** in the section of interest and use it as a value of *indexer.md.filter*.

Of course, if the site provides sitemaps, you'd know about all the URLs it contains in advance and in that case you'd be able to rely on the URL filter alone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Julien! Sadly sitesmap is not a reliable option. I guess we'd go with the filter at indexing step.

Comment: Hi Julian, related to the above issue, is there a way to stop crawling once you reach a certain URL for example once the crawler reaches `world/new/*` it should not go any deeper. I know this can be done by setting max depth but the depth can sometimes vary. If the pages under `world/new/` are my target it would be pointless for me to crawl any further and follow links out from those pages. Is there an elegant way of doing this using SC?

Comment: You could write a custom URL filter to prevent any URLs not in world/new but only if you are in world/new?
Since you are adding a metadata to flag urls in world/new for filtering as part of the indexing, you could use the FastURLFilter (see https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters) with a scope on the metadata targeting. That would be elegant if the metadata was created before the filtering step, which is not necessarily the case.